# Set up interfaces file on Debian for Lan

Tags: debian, networking

A friend set up my Raspberry Pi so that it creates its own wireless network and I can connect to it through SSH over the air. The /etc/network/interfaces file looks like this:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255

up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat
```

It's great. The Pi hosts its own wifi network, I can join the network from my laptop and connect to the Pi through `ssh pi@192.168.1.1`.

**But now I need the Pi to access the internet**. I connect it to my router with an ethernet cable but it doesn't really work. I can `ping 8.8.8.8` and get a response. But `ping google.com` fails. So there is a DNS problem.

I tried

- adding `nameserver 8.8.8.8` at the end of /etc/network/interfaces
- adding `allow-hotplug eth0` before `iface eth0 inet dhcp`

both of which didn't help.

I looked at the router configuration but didn't quite know what to look for. See screenshots below. One thing I noticed is that the Pi's wlan0 ip is static and set to `192.168.1.1` which is the same address that the router claims for itself (?). But then I thought: Hey, that's a wifi issue and should have nothing to do with my current LAN problem. Correct? Any ideas?
[image: Router config 1]
[image: Router config 2]

This is the content of `/etc/iptables.ipv4.nat`:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Mon Aug 11 15:58:35 2014
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [32:5915]
:INPUT ACCEPT [30:4763]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [3:226]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Aug 11 15:58:35 2014
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Mon Aug 11 15:58:35 2014
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [214:21125]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [111:13809]
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Aug 11 15:58:35 2014
```

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect. IP address conflict is the key here. Provide another subnet for your WiFi network or (probably better) bridge WiFi AP interface with the ethernet.

iptables may also be blocking some traffic. Please provide */etc/iptables.ipv4.nat* contents.

[ignore this paragraph if you go for bridging as advised] You may also be missing a DNS proxy software on your R.Pi. dnsmasq is a nice choice, as it provides both DNS and DHCP service with reasonable defaults for a small router.

Comment: "Provide another subnet for your WiFi network or bridge WiFi AP interface with the ethernet." Can you expplain what both options mean exactly?

Comment: I added the content of `/etc/iptables.ipv4.nat` above.

Comment: @bootsmaat: He means that you cannot use the `192.168.1.0/24` subnet for both `eth0` and `wlan0`. You need to choose two different subnets for each interface (for example, `192.168.1.0/24` and `192.168.2.0/24`). Note that anything in `192.168.0.0/16` can be used for private IP addressing (along with `10.0.0.0/8` and `172.16.0.0/12`, but that's usually used for larger networks).

Comment: @bootsmaat And the reasons for bridging - why to route/NAT your traffic twice? This can cause problems with port forwarding (if your router supports uPNP, it'll be unusable). If you bridge wlan0 with eth0, you will be able to connect directly to your eth. subnet from WiFi - no need for firewall, DNS, DHCP on R.Pi. - all this will be configured on the router. On Debian bridging can be configured directly from */etc/network/interfaces*, see `man 5 bridge-utils-interfaces`. And if you want to separate your networks (cable from wireless) , consider VLANs and different firewall zones on router.

Comment: @saiarcot895 What lines do I change exactly to achieve this?

Comment: @sam_pan_mariusz I'm not sure I understand the bridge concept yet but I will look into `man 5 bridge-utils-interfaces`, thanks. "why to route/NAT your traffic twice?" Are you talking about */etc/iptables.ipv4.nat*?

Comment: @bootsmaat I meant the whole concept. You're currently NAT-ing on both R.Pi and again on the main router. With bridging, you will skip the former step.

Comment: @sam_pan_mariusz would you mind sharing how my *interfaces* file would look like with a bridge set up? I read about [bridge-utils-interfaces](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?sektion=5&query=bridge-utils-interfaces&apropos=0&manpath=sid&locale=en) but find the concept a bit overwhelming. I'm also afraid of doing wild guesses because I may break the wifi connectivity (it has happened before when I editet *interfaces*) and it's the only way for me to connect to the Pi.